# yourlabs-subscription error -- Caught VariableDoesNotExist while rendering

Tags: django, subscription, django-apps

I have been trying to use the updated yourlabs subscription example, and the installation has worked fine except that

- Each of the views in the subscription app returns the request variable in the render to template.
- this `request context` variable is not received in the template and as a result I am getting the following error

  `Caught VariableDoesNotExist while rendering: Failed lookup for key [request] in u`

Since this is being returned in every view I can't solve this problem by making some tweaks in a particular template

Comment: The views in yourlabs-subscription use shortcuts.render and do not pass the request object in the context. It passes the request object to django.shortcut.render so that it can run context processors. django.core.context_processors.request is the context processor that sets request in the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because `request` isn't in your template's context and the template is using some template code that expected it to be there. That code (e.g. a custom template tag) should [better handle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#passing-template-variables-to-the-tag) `VariableDoesNotExist`

In addition, your views probably shouldn't return `request` in every response explicitly. Let Django handle this for you.

To do this, add the [request template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) that ships with Django to your [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS):

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    ...
)
```

If you are already using this template context processor, ensure that `render_to_response` is called with `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` as the final argument (the below example is from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext)):

```
def some_view(request):
# ...
return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                          my_data_dictionary,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This ensures that all the dicts returned by the template context processors in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` are passed to the template.

You could also use the [`render`shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#render), which will automatically render the template with an instance of `Requestcontext`.

Another option added in Django 1.3 is the [`TemplateResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/template-response/#using-templateresponse-and-simpletemplateresponse), which will also use an instance of `RequestContext`.

Comment: The render shortcut *is* what yourlabs-subscription views use.